# java codility Max-Counters

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have been trying to solve the below task:

You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

```
    increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
    max_counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
```

A non-empty zero-indexed array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

```
    if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
    if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max_counter.
```

For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
```

the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:

```
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 3, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 4, 2)
```

The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

```
struct Results {
  int * C;
  int L;
};
```

Write a function:

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M);
```

that, given an integer N and a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of M integers, returns a sequence of integers representing the values of the counters.

The sequence should be returned as:

```
    a structure Results (in C), or
    a vector of integers (in C++), or
    a record Results (in Pascal), or
    an array of integers (in any other programming language).
```

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
```

the function should return [3, 2, 2, 4, 2], as explained above.

Assume that:

```
    N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000];
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N+M);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**Here is my solution:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

        final int condition = N + 1;
        int currentMax = 0;
        int countersArray[] = new int[N];

        for (int iii = 0; iii < A.length; iii++) {
            int currentValue = A[iii];
            if (currentValue == condition) {
                Arrays.fill(countersArray, currentMax);
            } else {
                int position = currentValue - 1;
                int localValue = countersArray[position] + 1;
                countersArray[position] = localValue;

                if (localValue > currentMax) {
                    currentMax = localValue;
                }
            }

        }

        return countersArray;
    }
}
```

Here is the code valuation:
https://codility.com/demo/results/demo6AKE5C-EJQ/

Can you give me a hint what is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem comes with this piece of code:

```
for (int iii = 0; iii < A.length; iii++) {
     ...
     if (currentValue == condition) {
         Arrays.fill(countersArray, currentMax);
     }
     ...
}
```

Imagine that every element of the array `A` was initialized with the value `N+1`. Since the function call `Arrays.fill(countersArray, currentMax)` has a time complexity of `O(N)` then overall your algorithm will have a time complexity `O(M * N)`. A way to fix this, I think, instead of explicitly updating the whole array `A` when the `max_counter` operation is called you may keep the value of last update as a variable. When first operation (incrementation) is called you just see if the value you try to increment is larger than the  `last_update`. If it is you just update the value with 1 otherwise you initialize it to `last_update + 1`. When the second operation is called you just update `last_update` to `current_max`. And finally, when you are finished and try to return the final values you again compare each value to `last_update`. If it is greater you just keep the value otherwise you return  `last_update`

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

        final int condition = N + 1;
        int currentMax = 0;
        int lastUpdate = 0;
        int countersArray[] = new int[N];

        for (int iii = 0; iii < A.length; iii++) {
            int currentValue = A[iii];
            if (currentValue == condition) {
                lastUpdate = currentMax
            } else {
                int position = currentValue - 1;
                if (countersArray[position] < lastUpdate)
                    countersArray[position] = lastUpdate + 1;
                else
                    countersArray[position]++;

                if (countersArray[position] > currentMax) {
                    currentMax = countersArray[position];
                }
            }

        }

        for (int iii = 0; iii < N; iii++) {
           if (countersArray[iii] < lastUpdate)
               countersArray[iii] = lastUpdate;
        }

        return countersArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory this sounds right, but I haven't tried it to see if that gives 100 points

Comment: This is assuming every array inputted is 1 less than N, which may not be the case?

Comment: This solution works 100%. As a hand to myself and others, can you please elaborate on the logic of `if (countersArray[position] < lastUpdate) countersArray[position] = lastUpdate + 1;` i.e. in english terms, why is it that you set the value to lastUpdate + 1, and not lastUpdate? Thanks

Comment: @mils , imagine we only set the counter at the `position` index to `lastUpdate`. In that case we only apply the `max_counter` operation while in reality we've seen at least two operations for it: both `max_counter` and `increase(position + 1)`. If it were not for the latter, we wouldn't even change this counter's value until the second (and the last one) for loop in the @sve 's solution.

Comment: Nice solution.  I applied your approach to get mine to 100%.  My take-away is that comparing values (with lots of < = > operations) is cheaper than assignment.  It cost too much to update all the counters every time.  The answer was instead to keep track of the current maximum value and the last "sweep", when everything was set to maximum.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that when you get lots of `max_counter` operations you get lots of calls to `Arrays.fill` which makes your solution slow.

You should keep a `currentMax` and a `currentMin`:

- When you get a `max_counter` you just set `currentMin = currentMax`.
- If you get another value, let's call it `i`:

  - If the value at position `i - 1` is smaller or equal to `currentMin` you set it to `currentMin + 1`.
  - Otherwise you increment it.

At the end just go through the counters array again and set everything less than `currentMin` to `currentMin`.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that I have developed and might be worth considering: http://codility.com/demo/results/demoM658NU-DYR/

Comment: @moda, do you mind explaining your code? I don't seem to understand how it was able to accomplish the maxcounter mission. While I understand the code, the approach was just so good that I never would think of solving it this way. So, if you could explain abit of why you took that approach?

Comment: How is it "another" though? @helpdesk , consider reading @sve 's solution above. Here the `B` variable is the equivalent of the `lastUpdate` one.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer. I converted it to swift 4 and it was nice and clean. I actually was astounded how easy it was. The instructions on this lesson was absolutely awful.

Answer (score 6):

This is the 100% solution of this question.

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.math.*;
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        int counter[] = new int[N];
        int n = A.length;
        int max=-1,current_min=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(A[i]>=1 && A[i]<= N){
                if(counter[A[i] - 1] < current_min) counter[A[i] - 1] = current_min;
                counter[A[i] - 1] = counter[A[i] - 1] + 1;
                if(counter[A[i] - 1] > max) max = counter[A[i] - 1];
            }
            else if(A[i] == N+1){
                current_min = max;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(counter[i] < current_min) counter[i] =  current_min;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding another Java 100 solution with some test cases it they're helpful.

```
// https://codility.com/demo/results/demoD8J6M5-K3T/ 77
// https://codility.com/demo/results/demoSEJHZS-ZPR/ 100
public class MaxCounters {

  // Some testcases
  // (1,[1,2,3]) = [1]
  // (1,[1]) = [1]
  // (1,[5]) = [0]
  // (1,[1,1,1,2,3]) = 3
  // (2,[1,1,1,2,3,1]) = [4,3]
  // (5, [3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4]) = (1, 0, 1, 4, 1)
  public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
      int length = A.length, maxOfCounter = 0, lastUpdate = 0;
      int applyMax = N + 1;
      int result[] = new int[N];

      for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
          if(A[i] == applyMax){
              lastUpdate = maxOfCounter;
          } else if (A[i] <= N)  {
              int position = A[i]-1;
              result[position] = result[position] > lastUpdate
                                        ? result[position] + 1 : lastUpdate + 1;
              // updating the max for future use
              if(maxOfCounter <=  result[position]) {
                  maxOfCounter = result[position];
              }
          }
     }
     // updating all the values that are less than the lastUpdate to the max value
     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
         if(result[i] < lastUpdate) {
             result[i] = lastUpdate;
         }
     }
     return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My **java** solution with a **detailed explanation** 100% Correctness, 100% Performance :

Time Complexity *O(N+M)*

```
 public static int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

    int[] counters = new int[N];
    //The Max value between all counters at a given time
    int max = 0;

    //The base Max that all counter should have after the "max counter" operation happens
    int baseMax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        //max counter Operation ==> updating the baseMax
        if (A[i] > N) {
            // Set The Base Max that all counters should have
            baseMax = max;

        }

        //Verify if the value is bigger than the last baseMax because at any time a "max counter" operation can happen and the counter should have the max value
        if (A[i] <= N && counters[A[i] - 1] < baseMax) {
            counters[A[i] - 1] = baseMax;
        }

        //increase(X) Operation => increase the counter value
        if (A[i] <= N) {
            counters[A[i] - 1] = counters[A[i] - 1] + 1;

            //Update the max
            max = Math.max(counters[A[i] - 1], max);
        }
    }

    //Set The remaining values to the baseMax as not all counters are guaranteed to be affected by an increase(X) operation in "counters[A[i] - 1] = baseMax;"
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (counters[j] < baseMax)
            counters[j] = baseMax;
    }

    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my C++ solution which got 100 on codility. The concept is same as explained above.

```
int maxx=0;
int lastvalue=0;
void set(vector<int>& A, int N,int X)
    {
        for ( int i=0;i<N;i++)
            if(A[i]<lastvalue)
                A[i]=lastvalue;
    }

vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++11

    vector<int> B(N,0);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
        {
            if(A[i]==N+1)
               lastvalue=maxx;

            else
            {   if(B[A[i]-1]<lastvalue)
                    B[A[i]-1]=lastvalue+1;
                else
                    B[A[i]-1]++;
                if(B[A[i]-1]>maxx)
                    maxx=B[A[i]-1];
            }

        }
        set(B,N,maxx);
    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A)
{
    std::vector<int> counters(N);
    auto max = 0;
    auto current = 0;

    for (auto& counter : A)
    {
        if (counter >= 1 && counter <= N)
        {
            if (counters[counter-1] < max)
                counters[counter - 1] = max;

            counters[counter - 1] += 1;

            if (counters[counter - 1] > current)
                current = counters[counter - 1];
        }
        else if (counter > N)
            max = current;

    }

    for (auto&& counter : counters)
        if (counter < max)
            counter = max;

    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.fill()` invocation inside array interation makes the program O(N^2)

[Here](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingJAFF4Q-6XB/) is a possible solution which has O(M+N) runtime.

The idea is -

1. For the second operation, keep track of max value that is achieved through increment, this is our base value till the current iteration, no values can't be less than this.
2. For the first operation, resetting the value to base value if needed before the increment.

   public static int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
       int counters[] = new int[N];

   ```
   int base = 0;
   int cMax = 0;

   for (int a : A) {
       if (a > counters.length) {
           base = cMax;
       } else {
           if (counters[a - 1] < base) {
               counters[a - 1] = base;
           }

           counters[a - 1]++;

           cMax = Math.max(cMax, counters[a - 1]);
       }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
       if (counters[i] < base) {
           counters[i] = base;
       }
   }

   return counters;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

```
  vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A) 
{
    std::vector<int> counter(N, 0); 
    int max = 0;
    int floor = 0;

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = A.begin();i != A.end(); i++)
    {
        int index = *i-1;
        if(*i<=N && *i >= 1)
        {
            if(counter[index] < floor)
              counter[index] = floor;
            counter[index] += 1;
            max = std::max(counter[index], max);
        }
        else
        {
            floor = std::max(max, floor);
        }
    }
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = counter.begin();i != counter.end(); i++)
    {
       if(*i < floor)
         *i = floor;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hera is my AC Java solution. The idea is the same as @Inwvr explained:

```
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        int[] count = new int[N];
        int max = 0;
        int lastUpdate = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] <= N){
                if(count[A[i]-1] < lastUpdate){
                    count[A[i]-1] = lastUpdate+1;   
                }
                else{
                    count[A[i]-1]++;
                }    
                max = Math.max(max, count[A[i]-1]);
            }
            else{
                lastUpdate = max;   
            }
        }  
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if(count[i] < lastUpdate)
                count[i] = lastUpdate;
        }    
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got 100 in PHP with some help from the above

```
function solution($N, $A) {
    $B = array(0);
    $max = 0;

    foreach($A as $key => $a) {
        $a -= 1;
        if($a == $N) {
            $max = max($B);
        } else {
            if(!isset($B[$a])) {
                $B[$a] = 0;
            }

            if($B[$a] < $max) {
                $B[$a] = $max + 1;
            } else {
                $B[$a] ++;
            }

        }

    }

    for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
        if(!isset($B[$i]) || $B[$i] < $max) {
            $B[$i] = $max;
        }

    }

    return $B;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another C++ solution to the problem.

The rationale is always the same.

1. Avoid to set to max counter all the counter upon instruction two, as this would bring the complexity to O(N*M).
2. Wait until we get another operation code on a single counter.
3. At this point the algorithm remembers whether it had met a max_counter and  set the counter value consequently.

Here the code:

```
vector<int> MaxCounters(int N, vector<int> &A) 
{
    vector<int> n(N, 0);
    int globalMax = 0;
    int localMax = 0;

    for( vector<int>::const_iterator it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); ++it)
    {
        if ( *it >= 1 && *it <= N)
        {
            // this is an increase op.
            int value = *it - 1;
            n[value] = std::max(n[value], localMax ) + 1;
            globalMax = std::max(n[value], globalMax);
        }
        else
        {
            // set max counter op.
            localMax = globalMax;
        }
    }

    for( vector<int>::iterator it = n.begin(); it != n.end(); ++it)
        *it = std::max( *it, localMax );

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100%, O(m+n)

```
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

    int[] counters = new int[N];
    int maxAIs = 0;
    int minAShouldBe = 0;

    for(int x : A) {
        if(x >= 1 && x <= N) {
            if(counters[x-1] < minAShouldBe) {
                counters[x-1] = minAShouldBe;
            }

            counters[x-1]++;

            if(counters[x-1] > maxAIs) {
                maxAIs = counters[x-1];
            }
        } else if(x == N+1) {
            minAShouldBe = maxAIs;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(counters[i] < minAShouldBe) {
            counters[i] = minAShouldBe;
        }
    }

    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my code, but its 88% cause it takes 3.80 sec for 10000 elements instead of 2.20

class Solution {

```
boolean maxCalled;

public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

int max =0;
int [] counters = new int [N];
    int temp=0;
    int currentVal = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    currentVal = A[i];
    if(currentVal <=N){
        temp = increas(counters,currentVal);
        if(temp > max){
        max = temp;
        }
    }else{
        if(!maxCalled)
        maxCounter(counters,max);
    }

    }

    return counters;

}


int increas (int [] A, int x){  
 maxCalled = false;
 return ++A[x-1];  
 //return t;
}

void maxCounter (int [] A, int x){
 maxCalled = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
 A[i] = x;
  }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Following my solution in JAVA (100/100).

```
public boolean isToSum(int value, int N) {
    return value >= 1 && value <= N;
}

public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    int[] res = new int[N];
    int max =0;
    int minValue = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < A.length; i++){
        int value = A[i];
        int pos = value -1;
        if ( isToSum(value, N)) {
            if( res[pos] < minValue) {
                res[pos] = minValue;
            }
            res[pos] += 1;
            if (max < res[pos]) {
                max = res[pos];
            }
        } else {
            minValue = max;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < res.length; i++){
        if ( res[i] < minValue ){
            res[i] = minValue;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is :

```
public class Solution {  

        public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

            int[] counters = new int[N];
            int[] countersLastMaxIndexes = new int[N];
            int maxValue = 0;
            int fixedMaxValue = 0;
            int maxIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
                if (A[i] <= N) {
                    if (countersLastMaxIndexes[A[i] - 1] != maxIndex) {
                        counters[A[i] - 1] = fixedMaxValue;
                        countersLastMaxIndexes[A[i] - 1] = maxIndex;

                    }
                    counters[A[i] - 1]++;
                    if (counters[A[i] - 1] > maxValue) {
                        maxValue = counters[A[i] - 1];
                    }
                } else {
                    maxIndex = i;
                    fixedMaxValue = maxValue;
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < countersLastMaxIndexes.length; i++) {
                if (countersLastMaxIndexes[i] != maxIndex) {
                    counters[i] = fixedMaxValue;
                    countersLastMaxIndexes[i] = maxIndex;
                }
            }

            return counters;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Java solution I updated values in solution[] only when needed. And finally updated solution[] with a right values.

```
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    int[] solution = new int[N];
    int maxCounter = 0;
    int maxCountersSum = 0;
    for(int a: A) {
        if(a >= 1 && a <= N) {
            if(solution[a - 1] < maxCountersSum)
                solution[a - 1] = maxCountersSum;
            solution[a - 1]++;
            if(solution[a - 1] > maxCounter)
                maxCounter = solution[a - 1];
        }
        if(a == N + 1) {
            maxCountersSum = maxCounter;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(solution[i] < maxCountersSum)
            solution[i] = maxCountersSum;
    }

    return solution;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my python solution:

```
def solution(N, A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    RESP = [0] * N
    MAX_OPERATION = N + 1
    current_max = 0
    current_min = 0
    for operation in A:
        if operation != MAX_OPERATION:
            if RESP[operation-1] <= current_min:
                RESP[operation-1] = current_min + 1
            else:
                RESP[operation-1] += 1

            if RESP[operation-1] > current_max:
                current_max = RESP[operation-1]
        else:
            if current_min == current_max:
                current_min += 1
            else:
                current_min = current_max

    for i, val in enumerate(RESP):
        if val < current_min:
            RESP[i] = current_min
    return RESP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sample_method(A,N=5):
    initial_array = [0,0,0,0,0]
for i in A:

    if(i>=1):
      if(i<=N):
        initial_array[i-1]+=1
      else:
        for a in range(len(initial_array)):
          initial_array[a]+=1
    print i
    print initial_array
```

Comment: try to give a small review of your solution

Comment: A short explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using python 3.6. The result is 100% correctness but 40% performance (most of them were because of timeout). Still cannot figure out how to optimize this code but hopefully someone can find it useful.

```
def solution(N, A):
    count = [0]*(N+1)
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        if A[i] >=1 and A[i] <= N:
            count[A[i]] += 1
        elif A[i] == (N+1): 
            count = [max(count)] * len(count)
    count.pop(0)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript:

```
function counters(numCounters: number, operations: number[]) {
const counters = Array(numCounters)

let max = 0
let currentMin = 0

for (const operation of operations) {
    if (operation === numCounters + 1) {
        currentMin = max
    } else {
        if (!counters[operation - 1] || counters[operation - 1] < currentMin) {
            counters[operation - 1] = currentMin
        }

        counters[operation - 1] = counters[operation - 1] + 1

        if (counters[operation - 1] > max) {
            max += 1
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < numCounters; i++) {
    if (!counters[i] || counters[i] < currentMin) {
        counters[i] = currentMin
    }
}

return counters
```

}

console.log(`solution=${counters(5, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4])}`)

Answer (score 0):

100 points JavaScript solution, includes performance improvement to ignore repeated max_counter iterations:

```
function solution(N, A) {
    let max = 0;
    let counters = Array(N).fill(max);
    let maxCounter = 0;

    for (let op of A) {
        if (op <= N && op >= 1) {
            maxCounter = 0;
            if (++counters[op - 1] > max) {
                max = counters[op - 1];
            }
        } else if(op === N + 1 && maxCounter === 0) {
            maxCounter = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
                counters[i] = max;   
            }
        }
    }

    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution in JAVA (100/100)

```
    class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int[] result = new int[N];
        int base = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int needToChange=A.length;;
        for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
            int X = A[k];
            if (X >= 1 && X <= N) {

                if (result[X - 1] < base) {
                    result[X - 1] = base;
                }
                result[X - 1]++;
                if (max < result[X - 1]) {
                    max = result[X - 1];
                }
            }
            if (X == N + 1) {
                base = max;
                needToChange= X-1;

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < needToChange; i++) {
            if (result[i] < base) {
                result[i] = base;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Java solution. It gives 100% but is very long (in comparison). I have used HashMap for storing counters.

Detected time complexity: O(N + M)

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
  final private Map<Integer, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
  private int maxCounterValue = 0;
  private int maxCounterValueRealized = 0;

  public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    if (N < 1) return new int[0];

    for (int a : A) {
      if (a <= N) {
        Integer current = counters.putIfAbsent(a, maxCounterValueRealized + 1);
        if (current == null) {
          updateMaxCounterValue(maxCounterValueRealized + 1);
        } else {
          ++current;
          counters.replace(a, current);
          updateMaxCounterValue(current);
        }
      } else {
        maxCounterValueRealized = maxCounterValue;
        counters.clear();
      }
    }

    return getCountersArray(N);
  }

  private void updateMaxCounterValue(int currentCounterValue) {
    if (currentCounterValue > maxCounterValue)
      maxCounterValue = currentCounterValue;
  }

  private int[] getCountersArray(int N) {
    int[] countersArray = new int[N];

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      Integer current = counters.get(j + 1);
      if (current == null) {
        countersArray[j] = maxCounterValueRealized;
      } else {
        countersArray[j] = current;
      }
    }

    return countersArray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution in python with 100 % 
[Codility Max counter 100%](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingUQ95SB-4GA/)

```
def solution(N, A):
"""
Solution at 100% - https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingUQ95SB-4GA/
Idea is first take the counter array of given size N
take item from main A one by one + 1 and put in counter array , use item as index
keep track of last max operation
at the end replace counter items with max of local or counter item it self
:param N:
:param A:
:return:
"""
global_max = 0
local_max = 0
# counter array
counter = [0] * N

for i, item in enumerate(A):
    # take item from original array one by one - 1 - minus due to using item as index
    item_as_counter_index = item - 1
    # print(item_as_counter_index)
    # print(counter)
    # print(local_max)
    # current element less or equal value in array and greater than 1
    #         if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
    if N >= item >= 1:
        # max of local_max counter at item_as_counter_index
        # increase counter array value and put in counter array
        counter[item_as_counter_index] = max(local_max, counter[item_as_counter_index]) + 1
        # track the status of global_max counter so far
        # this is operation K
        global_max = max(global_max, counter[item_as_counter_index])
    #         if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.
    elif item == N + 1:
        # now operation k is as local max
        # here we need to replace all items in array with this global max
        # we can do using for loop for array length but that will cost bigo n2 complexity
        # example -  for i, item in A: counter[i] = global_max
        local_max = global_max
    # print("global_max each step")
    # print(global_max)

# print("local max so far....")
# print(local_max)
# print("counter - ")
# print(counter)
# now counter array - replace all elements which are less than the local max found so far
# all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter
for i, item in enumerate(counter):
    counter[i] = max(item, local_max)

return counter
```

result = solution(1, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4])
print("Sol " + str(result))

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingSJ8M5F-V7J/)

Got 100% result with O ( N + M )

```
class Solution {
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8

    int max = 0;
    int[] counter = new int[N];
    int upgrade = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( A[i] <= N )
        {
            if ( upgrade > 0 && upgrade > counter[A[i] - 1 ] )
            {
                counter[A[i] - 1] = upgrade; 
            }

            counter[A[i] - 1 ]++;

            if ( counter[A[i] - 1 ] > max )
                {
                    max = counter[A[i] - 1 ];
                }
        }
        else
        {
            upgrade = max;
        }

    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( counter[i] < upgrade)
        {
            counter[i] = upgrade;
        }
    }

    return counter;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Java 100%/100%, no imports

```
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
```

int[] counters = new int[N];

    int currentMax = 0;
    int sumOfMaxCounters = 0;
    boolean justDoneMaxCounter = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length ; i++) {

        if (A[i]  <= N) {

            justDoneMaxCounter = false;
            counters[A[i]-1]++;
            currentMax = currentMax < counters[A[i]-1] ? counters[A[i]-1] : currentMax;

        }else if (!justDoneMaxCounter){

            sumOfMaxCounters += currentMax;     
            currentMax = 0;
            counters = new int[N];
            justDoneMaxCounter = true;

        }
    }


    for (int j = 0; j < counters.length; j++) {
        counters[j] = counters[j] + sumOfMaxCounters;
    }

    return counters;
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your first post on StackOverflow. For good answeres it would be nice if you do not only post your code, but also explain what and why you changed specific things.

Answer (score 0):

python solution: 100% 100%

```
def solution(N, A):
    c = [0] * N

    max_element = 0
    base = 0
    for item in A:

        if item >= 1 and N >= item:
            c[item-1] = max(c[item-1], base) + 1
            max_element = max(c[item - 1], max_element)
        elif item == N + 1:
            base = max_element

    for i in range(N):
        c[i] = max (c[i], base)
    return c
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Using applyMax to record max operations

Time complexity:
O(N + M)

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        
        int max = 0, applyMax = 0;;
        int[] result = new int[N];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
            int a = A[i];
            
            if (a == N + 1) {
                applyMax = max;
            }
            
            if (1 <= a && a <= N) {
                result[A[i] - 1] = Math.max(applyMax, result[A[i] - 1]);
                max = Math.max(max, ++result[A[i] - 1]);
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            if (result[i] < applyMax) {
                result[i] = applyMax;
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a c++ solution with 100% score:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

void increase(int N, std::vector<int>& counters, int minCounter, int& max){
    //assert(N >= 1 && size_t(N - 1) < counters.size());
    auto n = counters[N - 1];
    counters[N - 1] = n <= minCounter ? minCounter + 1 : n + 1;
    if(counters[N - 1] > max) {
        max = counters[N - 1];
    }
}

vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A) {
    auto minCounter = 0;
    auto max = 0;
    std::vector<int> counters(N, 0);
    auto allEquals = true;
    for(auto i : A) {
        if(1 <= i && i <= N) {
            increase(i, counters, minCounter, max);
            allEquals = false;
        } else if(i == N + 1 && !allEquals) {
            minCounter = max;
            allEquals = true;
        }
    }
    
    for(auto& c : counters) {
        c = std::max(c, minCounter);
    }
    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only want to show, how a 77 % - Solution could look like:

```
 public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    int K = 0;
    int[] B = new int[N];
    for (int a : A)
        if (a > N) Arrays.fill(B, K);
        else K = Math.max(K, ++B[a-1]);
    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line increases the complexity:

```
Arrays.fill(countersArray, currentMax);
```

The solution is that setting a counter to maximum only when being processed and finally adding a final loop to align all to last maximum.

Here is another Java solution with score of %100:

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingA83U7Y-ESQ/

```
public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
    int[] counters = new int[N];
    int max = 0;
    int lastMaximization = 0;
    for (int command : A) {
        if (command < N + 1) {
            int index = command - 1;
            counters[index] = Math.max(lastMaximization, counters[index]) + 1;
            max = Math.max(max, counters[index]);
        } else {
            lastMaximization = max;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
        counters[i] = Math.max(lastMaximization, counters[i]);
    }

    return counters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codility 100% Score using Java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

        int[] res = new int[N];

        int counterMax = 0;
        int lastMax = 0;


        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if( (A[i]>=1) && (A[i] <= N) ){
                
                if(res[A[i]-1] <= lastMax){
                    res[A[i]-1] = lastMax + 1;
                }
                else if(res[A[i]-1] > lastMax ){
                    res[A[i]-1] += 1;
                }


                if( res[A[i]-1] > counterMax ){
                    counterMax = res[A[i]-1];
                }
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
             
            }
            else{
                
                lastMax = counterMax;
                //Arrays.fill(res,counterMax);
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
            }
        }


        for(int i=0; i< res.length; i++){
            if(res[i] <= lastMax){
                res[i] = lastMax;
            }
        }
        return res;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int[] res = new int[N];
        int base = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i : A) {
            if (i > N) {
                base = max;
            } else {
                if (res[i-1] >= base) {
                    res[i-1] += 1;
                } else {
                    res[i-1] =base + 1;
                }
                max = Math.max(max, res[i-1]);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            if(res[i] < base) {
                res[i] = base;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.